# How to decrease the UIFont size and show large sentence one line UILabel iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, fonts, uilabel

I have an UILabel in my iPhone app. I want to show large sentence in UILabel in a single line.  That means I want to decrease the font size and show the full text in a visible area. I don't want to show it in multiple lines. Can anyone please help me to do this?

My code is:

```
textViewLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 5, 194, 20)];
textViewLabel.text = @"I have an UILabel in my iPhone app. I have want";
textViewLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
textViewLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
textViewLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
textViewLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

CGSize maximumLabelsize2 = CGSizeMake(194,20);
CGSize expectedLabelsize2 = [result sizeWithFont:textViewLabel.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelsize2 lineBreakMode:textViewLabel.lineBreakMode]; 
CGRect messagesFrame = textViewLabel.frame;
messagesFrame.size.height = expectedLabelsize2.height;
textViewLabel.frame = messagesFrame;
```

Any one please help me to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That bit about [`textViewLabel.numberOfLines`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/numberOfLines) might be important.

Comment: May be this similar question would help you out!!

[Font Size][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382976/multiline-uilabel-with-adjustsfontsizetofitwidth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change numberOfLines property from

```
textViewLabel.numberOfLines = 0; // 0 means as many lines as needed
```

to

```
textViewLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
```

add

```
textViewLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

Conside setting

```
textViewLabel.minimumFontSize = someValue; // default is 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this property:

```
myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
[textViewLabel  setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```