# adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth is not working in ios 5 if the label is displayed in 2 lines

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel

I'm using `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to shrink the label's size.
But things were fine until I tested it in a device with ios 5. :P

```
self.mainTitleLabel.numberOfLines=2; 
self.mainTitleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
self.mainTitleLabel.minimumFontSize = 4;
```

This is working fine in ios 6 and not in ios 5.

Also in ios 5, its shrinking when I give like this,

```
self.mainTitleLabel.numberOfLines=1;
```

Why the label is not shrinking if its having 2 lines ?
What might be the possible solution for this ?

Note: The text wont go beyond 2 lines as per the static data.

Comment: +1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382976/multiline-uilabel-with-adjustsfontsizetofitwidth

Answer (score 3):

This property is effective only when the numberOfLines property is set to 1.

Comment: But its effective in ios 6. Why is that?
Any other possible solution ?

Comment: Check the documentation on UILabel.

Answer (score 3):

I would also like to add **minimumFontSize** was deprecated in iOS 6 in favor of **minimumScaleFactor**