# Maximum font size UIFont

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uilabel, uitextview

I'm trying to use `UIFont fontWithName:size:` in a `UILabel` and am getting crappy resolution at sizes above 250 points. I'm having issues with custom and system fonts. I've had the same issue with UITextView as well.

I'm doing all this programmatically, needing to scale a UILabel and the font size up to very large font sizes.

Does anyone know why I'm having issues?

Comment: Sounds strange. Are you rendering the text manually?

Comment: rendering programmatically, not through storyboard.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091115/iphone-sdk-calculate-max-font-size/11810409#11810409.

Comment: @Eric is ur problem solved?

Comment: We aren't having trouble calculating the size we need. We are losing quality as the UILabel font size increases.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a limitation of UIKit. Have you tried rendering your text to an image using CoreText instead?